# Scite Lua Scripting Extension API Beginner

Tags: lua, scintilla, scite

This may be a stupid question but how do I access things like editor:addtext()?

http://www.scintilla.org/PaneAPI.html

http://www.scintilla.org/SciTELua.html

I can see how to use it, but don't know where to put it.  Where are the functions accessible from?  And how do they get run?  Can it work from any normal Lua program?

Comment: Please, it would be useful to give more informations about what you try to achieve and what you already have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stupid example:
1. Open menu "Options" -> "Open Lua Startup Script"
2. Write any Lua code, e.g. `print('Selected: <'..editor:GetSelText()..'>')`
3. Press `Ctrl-S` (as if you want to save this file), your script will be immediately executed, output will appear in the output pane (on the right).
4. Repeat steps 2-3

---

Less stupid example:
Insert this into `SciTEGlobal.properties`

```
ext.lua.startup.script=$(SciteDefaultHome)/your_script.lua

#print length of selected text
command.33.*=PrintSelectionLength
command.subsystem.33.*=3
command.mode.33.*=savebefore:no
command.shortcut.33.*=F1

# User defined key commands
user.shortcuts=\
F1|1133|\
Ctrl+Shift+V|IDM_PASTEANDDOWN|\
Ctrl+PageUp|IDM_PREVFILE|\
Ctrl+PageDown|IDM_NEXTFILE|

user.context.menu=\
Selection Length    (F1)|1133|\
||\
Toggle Output|IDM_TOGGLEOUTPUT|
```

Insert this in `your_script.lua`

```
function PrintSelectionLength()
   local sel = editor:GetSelText()
   print(#sel..' chars selected')
   print(table.concat({sel:byte(1,-1)},','))
end
```

Now you can press `F1` to see ASCII codes of symbols under selection while editing any file in SciTE.

Comment: Is there any way to get at those functions while Scite is running and you're working on another document?

Comment: Yes, any changes in `SciTEGlobal.properties` are applying on-the-fly without restarting SciTE.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm getting a handle on it